# Pandas, Include FileName in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

I have some Python Pandas code to read in multiple files from the same folder. I would like to include the individual file names too.My code, which works fine, is pulling in all the data I need. However I need to include the filename as a separate column too. I'm having a bit of a brain freeze here. Can anyone help? ;

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path =r'C:\my_file_path\Misc' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, dtype=str, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_, axis=0, irnore_index = TRUE)
```

Comment: Modify your read_csv line: `df = pd.read_csv(...).assign(filename=file_)`

Comment: seems a waste to add a whole column just to have a reference to a file name, why not just have a dict where the filename is the key, and the values are the dfs? Or add it as an attribute e.g. `df.filename = file_` however, attributes won't copy or persist if you write to csv

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This worked perfectly.